# How to effectively guess the initial values for a Poincaré section?

Tags: plotting, table, sow-reap

I have the following code, which plots the Poincaré section for the trajectory of particles around a symmetric black hole:

```
kr = 100; kθ = 25; rh = 2; rc = 3.2; θc = 0; κ = \
0.25;

f[r_] := 2 κ (r - rh)

H[r_, pr_, θ_, pθ_] := -Sqrt[1 - f[r]] pr + Sqrt[
  pr^2 + pθ^2/r^2] + 1/2 kr (r - rc)^2 + 
  1/2 kθ (rh θ - rc θc)^2
H0[{r_, pr_, θ_, pθ_}] := -Sqrt[1 - f[r]] pr + Sqrt[
  pr^2 + pθ^2/r^2] + 1/2 kr (r - rc)^2 + 
  1/2 kθ (rh θ - rc θc)^2

{a1, b1, c1, 
  d1} = {D[H[r[t], pr[t], θ[t], pθ[t]], pr[t]], 
  D[H[r[t], pr[t], θ[t], pθ[t]], 
   pθ[t]], -D[H[r[t], pr[t], θ[t], pθ[t]], 
    r[t]], -D[
    H[r[t], pr[t], θ[t], pθ[t]], θ[
     t]]}; abcd = {r'[t] == a1, pr'[t] == c1, θ'[t] == b1, 
  pθ'[t] == d1};

ClearAll[solution];
solution[R_, PR_] := 
 Reap@NDSolve[
   Flatten[{abcd, {r[0] == R, pr[0] == PR, θ[0] == 0, 
      pθ[0] == initial[R, PR]}, 
     WhenEvent[θ[t] == 0 && θ'[t] > 0, 
      Sow[{r[t], pr[t]}]]}], {}, {t, 0.0, T}, MaxSteps -> Infinity]

T = 4000.0;

energy = 75.0;

constraint = (pθ /. 
     Solve[energy == H[r, pr, 0, pθ], pθ]) // Last;

ClearAll[initial];
initial[r_?NumericQ, pr_?NumericQ] := Evaluate[constraint]

tab = Table[solution[R, 0.0] // Last // First, {R, 2.72, 3.75, 0.01}];

ListPlot[tab, PlotRange -> All, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[.003], AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
 ImageSize -> Large, FrameLabel -> {r, Subscript[p, r]}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 10], GridLines -> None]
```

which results in the desired plot:

[image: psection]

In this case, I was reproducing results from a [published paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370269318308979), so I was easily able to input the desired range of `R` as

`{R, 2.72, 3.75, 0.01}`, since it was in the paper. But suppose I was making the Poincaré section for the first time, and let's say I guess the range to be `{R, 2.01, 4, 0.01}`:

```
tab = Table[solution[R, 0.0] // Last // First, {R, 2.01, 4, 0.01}]
```

which gives me warning messages and some missing values.

also, it will not give me any plot whatsoever.

So, is there any way using Mathematica by which I can get the **desired range**?

**Edit:** Applying the tricks provided by @[E. Chan-López](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/53427/e-chan-l%C3%B3pez) and @[Daniel Huber](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/46318/daniel-huber), also taking into consideration the useful comment by @[Alex Trounev](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/58388/alex-trounev), I tried to scan for desired range using:

```
tab = Quiet@
  Table[If[Flatten[solution[R, 0.0]] === {}, Nothing, 
    solution[R, 0.0] // Last // First], {R, 2.01, 4, 0.1}]

tmp = Flatten[tab, 1]

MinMax /@ {tmp[[All, 1]], tmp[[All, 2]]}
```

which gives me the range as:

```
{{0.594091, 3.90931}, {-26.3422, 868.724}}
```

It's still not quite correct. I even tried changing the step size but to no avail. Isn't there any better method to find the [**Basin of attraction**](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BasinofAttraction.html)?

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you try to reproduce results from the paper linked, then you should know that black hole horizon is given at `r=2`. So you should look any trajectory with initial condition `r[0]>2`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev, ah you are absolutely right. I made a blunder in the example. Let me edit that. My question is still the same though, how to effectively decide the initial values.

Comment: Could you remove wrong range `{R, 1, 2, 0.01}` from your post as well?

Comment: Ah yes sorry my mistake. Let me do that as well.

Comment: Thank you very much (+1).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A somewhat dirty solution is to do the following:

```
tab = Quiet@
Table[If[Flatten[solution[R, 0.0]] === {}, Nothing, 
solution[R, 0.0] // Last // First], {R, 2.72, 3.75, 0.01}]
```

Comment: Thanks for solving one issue, but still the bigger issue is that of finding the exact range, as you can see, plotting this would not give me the entire section. I am not sure but maybe it's called "basin of attraction" in literature.

Comment: @codebpr Now I understand better what you are looking for, the basin of attraction is another task. :)

Comment: Actually, I tried the same with your interactive [Poincare clicker](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ClickPoincarePlot2D/) and faced the same issue there as well. Do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: @E.Chan-López Please, pay attention that range `{R, 1, 2, 0.01}` is wrong in this problem since BH horizon is at `R=2`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thanks, Alex! From the beginning I did not pay attention to it, as I understood that it was only the problem of avoiding table values where there is no solution and an empty list is added. In fact, NDSolve detects singularities right in that incorrect range.

Comment: @E.Chan-López Could you remove wrong range from your answer?

Comment: @AlexTrounev The incorrect range has been removed. :)

Comment: @E.Chan-López Thank you  very much (+1).

Comment: @E.Chan-López the shortest and best one was your Resource function. I am not sure why it is not functioning on my MMA 14 (Windows). Not even the example problems mentioned [here](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ClickPoincarePlot2D/).

Comment: @codebpr Try `ResourceRemove@ResourceFunction["ClickPoincarePlot2D"]` and then run the resource function again.

Comment: It gave me some hexadecimal values like `"42be8df-05c1-4d37-a985-0e31dc925aef"` and then again after running the resource function, same non-functionality.

Comment: @codebpr Please, restart your kernel.

Comment: Restarted, still no progress. I will try to check if it works in MMA13 in a different system and let you know.

Comment: @codebpr I had the same problem on version 14, but I now know how to force it to install correctly. Try `ResourceFunction["ClickPoincarePlot2D", ResourceVersion -> "1.0.1"]`

Comment: @E.Chan-López tried this too and still not working in version 14. The same issue in version 13, all the methods that you mentioned are not working, even after taking care of the `PlotHighlighting` option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151810/discussion-between-e-chan-lopez-and-codebpr).

Comment: Thanks a lot, @E.Chan-López, for rectifying my error. I hope this problem can be easily solved by your resource function.

Comment: @codebpr The basic example works. In the screenshot that appears in the resource function, notice that the initial condition must be taken very close to zero. Take one with the cursor very close to zero, and you'll see it works.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9kGp.jpg

Comment: Yes, you are right. The first click is the crucial one. I wish there was a way by which I could cite your algorithm in my paper. Normally in stack sites like [math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) there is a cite button which makes it easy for researchers like us to cite in papers. I have asked this [question](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2766/78049) on meta regarding this. Hopefully, the moderators/creators will try to consider this.

Comment: @codebpr Please ask about references to resource functions in a new post, as it would be useful for other users who wish to put resource functions to professional use. There is something additional I want to submit to update `ClickPoincarePlot2D`. Do you mind if I include you as a co-author? I'll take advantage of the fact that I'm going to include one of the systems that you considered in your posts, specifically the system where I added the solution using `ClickPane`.

Comment: It would be my pleasure to be a co-author, please include anything you like. I am also going to ask a new question regarding this now.

Comment: @codebpr I assume there is no LaTeX citation style requirement for resource functions.  Surely the citation style is free and only requires adding the link in addition to the name of the authors.  You can modify your question in this sense to avoid its closure.

Answer (score 5):

You may get the range directly from tab or the plot.

To get the range from "tab", you first flatten "tab" to get the points and then use MinMax:

```
tmp = Flatten[tab, 1];
MinMax /@ {tmp[[All, 1]], tmp[[All, 2]]}

{{2.23392, 3.91358}, {-26.4203, 167.055}}
```

To get the range from the plot: Say "pl" is your plot, then with "AbsoluteOptions":

```
AbsoluteOptions[p, PlotRange]

{PlotRange -> {{2.19893, 3.91358}, {-26.4203, 167.055}}}
```

Comment: But that's when I already defined `tab`. My question is the other way around. How to find 'range' when I don't have a prior plot to look at? Basically, the basin of attraction.

Comment: I changed my answer and added the possibility to get the range from tab.

Comment: It works for this tab but sadly not for the modified one. Please see the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this problem is easily resolved by carefully choosing the approximate plot range using the **ResourceFunction["ClickPoincarePlot2D"]** developed by @[E. Chan-López](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/53427/e-chan-l%C3%B3pez) as shown below:

```
kr = 100; kθ = 25; rh = 2; rc = 3.2; θc = 0; κ =0.25;
f[r_] := 2  κ  (r - rh)

ham[r_, pr_, θ_, pθ_] := -Sqrt[1 - f[r]] pr + Sqrt[
  pr^2 + pθ^2/r^2] + 1/2 kr (r - rc)^2 + 
  1/2 kθ (rh θ - rc θc)^2

H := Function[{S}, -S[[2]] Sqrt[1 - 0.5  (-2 + S[[1]])] + Sqrt[
   S[[2]]^2 + S[[4]]^2/S[[1]]^2] + 50  (-3.2 + S[[1]])^2 + 
   25/2  (0 + 2  S[[3]])^2]

{a1, b1, c1, 
  d1} = {D[ham[r[t], pr[t], θ[t], pθ[t]], pr[t]], 
  D[ham[r[t], pr[t], θ[t], pθ[t]], 
   pθ[t]], -D[ham[r[t], pr[t], θ[t], pθ[t]], 
    r[t]], -D[
    ham[r[t], pr[t], θ[t], pθ[t]], θ[
     t]]}; hameqns = {r'[t] == a1, pr'[t] == c1, θ'[t] == b1, 
  pθ'[t] == d1};

cross = θ[t];
recover = {r[t], pr[t]};

ResourceFunction[
  "ClickPoincarePlot2D"][hameqns, H, 75.0, t, 6000, cross, recover, 
{PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[1], PlotRange -> {{2, 4}, Automatic}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, PlotHighlighting -> None}]
```

[image: click-poincare]